# memory exhausted while trying to remove sd=0 column

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove numeric columns with sd=0, and this error "Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)" pops up, my "data" was read with fread.

```
data2 <- data[ - as.numeric(which(apply(data, 2, var) == 0))]
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You  can try to simplify this expression using several variables

Comment: If you're really trying to remove columns, you should put a comma in front on your internal code, alongside  `with=F`. It'll become `data[, - as.numeric(which(apply(data, 2, var) == 0)), with=F]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
idx <- data[, sapply(.SD, function(col) var(col)==0)]
data2 <- data[, -idx, with=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colVars` from `matrixStats` package which is usually fast.

```
data2 <- data[matrixStats::colVars(as.matrix(data)) != 0, ]
```

Comment: Tried matrixStats, and had this error>>Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.4 Gb